# If clause in a conditional sentence: didn't have vs hadn't

Tags: grammaticality, conditionals, negation, sequence-of-tenses, do-support

I have a sentence in an exam that says:

> [1] I WOULD COME if I DIDN'T HAVE other plans.

Is it right to say the sentence:

> [2] I would come if I HADN'T other plans.

I am having trouble deciding.

Comment: Both mean the same, although _didn't have_ is more natural in modern English.

Comment: They're both grammatically OK and have the same meaning, though 1. is more likely. The difference is grammatical: in 1. "have" is a lexical verb while in 2. it's an auxiliary verb. Note the requirement for _do_-support in 1. as is normal with lexical verbs in negatives and interrogatives.

Comment: If it's the *verb* that's being negated, we don't generally like to negate ***to have*** in such contexts - we'd much rather include "do-support" so we can negate auxiliary ***to do*** instead. Alternatively, another way to avoid that non-idiomatic negating ***hadn't*** is to negate the ***object noun*** instead: *I would come if I had **no other plans**.* Imho, negated do-support is more likely when the scenario being referenced is *known to be untrue* (completely hypothetical "irrealis"), but negating the object is more likely if the speaker himself doesn't [yet] know if he *will be* busy.

Comment: I'd say << [2] I would come if I HADN'T other plans >> models on << [2'] I wouldn't come if I HAD other plans >> with _had_ again a lexical verb. But 'hadn't' for 'did not possess' is often unidiomatic ('I hadn't any other plans' but *'I hadn't other plans').

Comment: Thank you both! This helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

> [1] *I WOULD COME if I DIDN'T HAVE other plans.*
>
> [2] *I would come if I HADN'T other plans.*

[1] and [2] are both grammatically OK and have the same meaning, though [1] is far more likely.

The difference is grammatical: in [1] "have" is a lexical verb while in [2] it's an auxiliary verb.

Note the requirement for *do*-support in 1. as is usual with lexical verbs in negatives and interrogatives.

Comment: In UK English, lexical *have* used with a possessive meaning can behave as an auxiliary and  contract with *not* and appear in question tags etc. However, in standard American English this is ungrammatical. It's one of the few well-known differences between the two varieties (although, I would argue it's marginally acceptable, at least, in US English given its existence in common well known idioms).

Comment: I'm aware that in some varieties of English, stative "have" is always a lexical verb.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** is the better of the two sentences.

**present**- I have got. Negative- I **haven't got**.

I have. Negative- I **don't have**. (I haven't- less usual)

**Past**- We usually use **didn't have** (NOT *hadn't*) in negative sentences.

...***I** **DIDN'T HAVE*** ...